# Мониторинг sonarqube с помощью zabbix

Tags: zabbix, sonarqube

Подскажите, как можно настроить мониторинг sonarqube c помощью zabbix.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону JMX.

SonarQube может отдавать метрики через JMX MBeans
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/monitoring/

Ну а Zabbix в свою очередь умеет работать с JMX
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring